# How to show Ajax message from JSF bean?

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces

I am trying to fire an alert with a message given from a java function. The system is as simple as this:

```
    public class AdminBean extends AbstractListBean {

    private Collection <Hours> A;
    private ModelDto selectedModel;
    private String message;

public void insert() {

        //some preparations
        setMessage("");

        if ( selectedModel!= null ) {

                try{

                //try insert of selected model
                setMessage("Success");

                }catch (Exception e) {

                    setMessage("Unespected Error");
                }

            }else{
                setMessage("Not available");
            }

        //getHttpServletRequest().setAttribute("message", getMessage());
        //FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(message)); 

    }
```

}

And, at client side, I have wrote the xhtml like this:

```
<a4j:commandLink styleClass="inscribirse" rendered="#{model.status eq 'N' and model.styleClass eq 'font-weight:bold;'}">
    <a4j:jsFunction name="okClicked" actionListener="#{AdminBean.insert}" oncomplete="reDirigir(message)">
    <a4j:actionparam name="message" assignTo="#{AdminBean.message}"/>
    </a4j:jsFunction>
   <h:outputText value="Inscribirse" />
   <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{AdminBean.selectedModel}" value="#{model}" />
</a4j:commandLink>
```

So, when the A4J command is clicked, the function "insert" runs, I could see it watching the database, but "reDirigir" function, is not working:

```
function reDirigir(c){

        alert(c);
        window.location.href='#{facesContext.externalContext.request.contextPath}/StrutsJsfServlet?beanName=menuBean&method=eventos';

        }
```

My intention is to show the message from bean, and then refresh page. Any suggestions?

Thank you very much!

PS: This xhtml code is inside an iteration for collection A and #{model} is the alias used in the iterator:

Comment: Are you using a4j with jsf 1.x, RichFaces 3 with JSF 1.x or RichFaces 4 with JSF 2?

Comment: The first option that you gave me (JSF 1.x, Richfaces 3.3.3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Solved.**

The problem was automatic Ids given by JSF, I solved that using:

```
<h:form prependId="false">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="okClicked" actionListener="#{AdminBean.insert}" oncomplete="reDirigir(message)">
```

This will not work. You will send "message" to your backing bean, but it won't  be sent back and may be used in your javascript function.

Assuming that you want to `alert(...)` the message (which in my opinion is kind of ugly) it's probably the easiest to have a hidden input field whose value is the message. Your commandLink will reRender this hidden field so you can access its value after the bean invocation via javascript.

With jQuery that might be as easy as `$('input#hidden_input_id').val()`

Your function `reDirigir` mayb look like this

```
function reDirigir() {
    alert($('input#hidden_input_id').val());
    window.location.href='#{facesContext.externalContext.request.contextPath}/StrutsJsfServlet?beanName=menuBean&method=eventos';
}
```

I can't tell if this redirect is correct like that, but the problem was that the "message" parameter actually didn't exist before. Without it, it should be working now.

Comment: you are right! I want to do an Alert just to see if the codes are working properly, then I will put some modal dialog o something similar. Thank you very much, I ll check it on this way, then I tell you. Thanks again!

Comment: In this case just take a modal panel and put a <h:outputText> with the message as the value there. reRender the modal panel with your commandLink and the message will already be there. With onComplete you will then display the modal panel. At least that's how I did it in RichFaces 4.2.

Comment: I was trying to do what you suggested, but it is not working, rerender fails: [<a4j:commandLink styleClass="inscribirse" rendered="#{model.status eq 'N' and taller.styleClass eq 'font-weight:bold;'}" reRender="inputMessage"><a4j:jsFunction name="okClicked" actionListener="#{adminBean.inscripcion}" oncomplete="reDirigir();" />] and [<div id="prueba-index" style="display:none"><span id="inputMessage">#{adminBean.message}</span></div>] . I do not know why reRender property is failing.